# Alternative to use hidden fields in GridView

Tags: asp.net, performance, datatable, hidden-field

I have the following asp:GridView control:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="DataBound">
      <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
             <ItemTemplate>                      

                  <input id="docKey_cell" class="key" runat="server" type="hidden"/>
                  <input id="docFname_cell" class="fileName" runat="server" type="hidden"/>
                  <span class="docTitle"><%# Eval("Title")%></span>

             </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
   ...
```

On a row double click I open via Jquery an external window passing the data from the hidden fields. In this specific case I just need to pass a documentID (as string) and the physical file name of the document presented in the row, therefore saving a further SQL Query to get this info in the new opened dialog.

Until now I often used this technique when I needed to have small data to be used with JQuery.

However I wondering whether is this an acceptable practice or is there a better approach that can improve performance or maintanability?

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the better approaches is to add custom attributes to the control with the information you need and use JQuery to access this attributes, I think this is a better approach

Comment: this way if the user double clicked you can access the information through $(this).attr("attributeName") and this will save you a lot of hassle of getting the correct hidden field

Comment: I edited the code: I will use CSS class in order to easily retrieve the proper hidden file from JQuery. Does the use of hidden fields have other cons? Otherwise it does not seem too bad continue using them instead of introduce custom attributes. Moreover it happens that I have different kinf of data to be provided as hidden fields, therefore not always the same.

Comment: +1 However, since using custom attrobutes will also a possible alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Opening a window just seems wrong.  Since you're already using jQuery, you can use it to [send off an Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to save the data.

As an alternative to using hidden fields, you can start using [HTML5 data-value attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) today!

Comment: In this case I need to open a window since from there I need to download the physical document from remote. I found necessary to open that external window, just to have in there the pop up "Save/Open" for the downloaded file.